# activiti - service task was frozen

Tags: activiti

I've a instance of workflow, but it freeze at service task. The class which handle for service task just do simple process (sure that don't have  infinite loop). It seem my JavaDelegate class wasn't called.

Any ideas about root cause?

Comment: Can you post your process definition ? One scenario were this would happen is if your have an asynchronous service task but no background task executor configured.

Comment: yep, my service task is asynchronous, but, It executed correctly in couple days ago, then it was frozen yesterday, I need to restart tomcat, then it's continue executing. I guess the activiti's core can not create instance of my delegate class, but no error log was written.